# Passing function as a class's template paremeter with unknown type

Tags: c++, templates

I know we can do something like this:

```
void f1(){ printf("1"); }
void f2(){ printf("2"); }

template <void F()>
class A{
public:
    void func(){
        F();
    }
};

int main(){
    A<f1> a1; a1.func(); // printing "1"
    A<f2> a2; a2.func(); // printing "2"
}
```

Then, is it possible without knowing the return and argument types of the function f1 and f2?
For example,

```
void f1(){ ... }
int f2(){ ... }

int main(){
    A<f1> a1; a1.f();
    A<f2> a2; a2.f();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's a bit hard to call a function that requires parameters, if the code does not know it needs to pass in parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++17, you might simply use `auto`

```
template <auto F>
class A{
public:
    void func(){
        F();
    }
};
```