# How to call a function with default parameters when used as non-type template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, auto, non-type-template-parameter

This is a follow-up of this question: [Passing function as a class's template paremeter with unknown type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65093457/passing-function-as-a-classs-template-paremeter-with-unknown-type?noredirect=1#comment115085079_65093457)

My navie idea was that [Jarod42s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65093489/4117728):

> ```
> template <auto F>
> class A{
> public:
>     void func(){
>         F();
>     }
> };
> ```

allows to use functions with default parameters as parameter to `A` and call them via `F()`. If this was possible, the above `A` could handle functions of arbitrary type, given all parameters have defaults.

However this fails:

```
void foo(int x= 0){}
double bar(int y=0,int x=0) {return 1;}

template <auto F>
class A{
public:
    void func(){
        F();
    }
};

int main(){
    A<&foo> a;
    a.func();  
}
```

[with error](https://godbolt.org/z/MKGhMs):

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'void A<F>::func() [with auto F = foo]':
<source>:14:12:   required from here
<source>:8:10: error: too few arguments to function
    8 |         F();
      |         ~^~
ASM generation compiler returned: 1
<source>: In instantiation of 'void A<F>::func() [with auto F = foo]':
<source>:14:12:   required from here
<source>:8:10: error: too few arguments to function
    8 |         F();
      |         ~^~
Execution build compiler returned: 1
```

Can the above `A` be fixed to call `foo` or `bar` without specializing for their exact type and use their default parameters?

Comment: Default values are not part of a function's signature. Inside of your template, the default values are lost. To do what you are attempting, you will have to wrap the function calls inside of a lambda or functor.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes I remember something like that. If there is really no way, the question is rather boring unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out by RemyLebeau in a comment:

> Default values are not part of a function's signature. Inside of your template, the default values are lost. To do what you are attempting, you will have to wrap the function calls inside of a lambda or functor

And that actually does not require to change anything about `A`:

```
int main(){
    A<[](){ return foo(); }> a;
    a.func();  
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/PvPz78)